# SIF installation Password Validation error

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

When installing Sitecore 9 Update 1 on-premises installation, receive the below error message for the database password validation. The marketingautomation database is created and fails during creating the user. The Password specified in the JSON files is complex including a UpperCase character, lowercase character, special char (@) and numbers. Can anyone please help to resolve this issue?

```
Info: Adding database (user id=sa;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS2016;initial catalog=sc9u1_MarketingAutomation)
Info: Adding database (MsDeploy.Site/dbFullSql[@path='user id=sa;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS2016;initial catalog=sc9u1_MarketingAutomation']/sqlScript)
Info: Opening SQL Connection with connection string 'data source=.;initial catalog=sc9u1_MarketingAutomation;user id=sa;pooling=False'. The 'transacted' setting for this connection is 'False'.
**Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE**
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "9" and "12". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"CREATE USER [marketingautomationuser] WITH PASSW"
 **Password validation failed. The password does not meet the requirements of the password filter DLL**. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
```

The link mentioned above is not useful since this is a generic exception.

**Update:** I was able to resolve this issue by changing the password in each of the installation JSON files.

Comment: I am facing the same error. Where you able to fix it?

Comment: I resolved this issue by changing the default TEST12345 password with a password according to my SQL Server Password Policies. Both JSON files xconnect-xp0.json and sitecore-XP0.json meed to be updated. Did you get chance to have a look at the question:- https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12056/sif-installation-throwing-password-validation-failed-exception

Answer (score 3):

**Strict password policy**

Make sure you use the Strict password policy recommended for SQL passwords.

- the use of both upper-case and lower-case letters (case sensitivity)
- inclusion of one or more numerical digits
- inclusion of special characters, such as @, #, $

Complete reference for password policy [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_policy)

**Validate using SIFless**

You can also validate your installation assets with SIFless.

Download SIFless from [here](https://bitbucket.org/RAhnemann/sif-less/downloads/SIFLess.zip). Complete reference [here](http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2017/10/introducing-sif-less-for-easy-sitecore-9-installation/).

Once you fill all the files of the SIFless. It will show you like this.

[image]

You can check my blog for complete guide to Sitecore 9 installation.

https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/sitecore-9-installation-download-install-validate-done/