# Sitecore 9 Installation - Password is too short

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am trying to install Sitecore 9 on my Windows 10 local developer machine runnin SQLExpress 2016.
I have to attend developers training soon and for that I need Sitecore 9 running.

For some reason, I cannot pass forward this error. My SQL Express admin password is `2!SiteCore` which is strong enough but it keeps complaining that `Error: Password validation failed. The password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is too short.`

It has been 24 hours for me and I have searched left right and center. I have tried many different options.

Please help

Thanks

Complete error message:

```
    Info: Adding database (user id=sc9;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=sitecore9_MarketingAutomation)
Info: Adding database (MsDeploy.Site/dbFullSql[@path='user id=sc9;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=sitecore9_MarketingAutomation']/sqlScript)
Info: Opening SQL Connection with connection string 'data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=sitecore9_MarketingAutomation;user id=sc9;pooling=False'. The 'transacted' setting for this connection is 'False'.
Error: Password validation failed. The password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is too short.
Error count: 1.
Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "9" and "12". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"CREATE USER [marketingautomationuser] WITH PASSW"
 Password validation failed. The password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is too short. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At C:\sitecore\install\installation.ps1:57 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:01:25
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\sitecore\install\xconnect-xp0.180608 (2).log
Invoke-CommandTask : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\Tasks\Invoke-WebDeployTask.ps1:36 char:2
+     Invoke-CommandTask -Path $Path -Arguments $msdeployArgs -TaskName ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask
```

Error points to the line 57 of my `installation.ps` which is last line below

```
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
    } 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose  // Line # 57
```

It has nothing to do with my SQL password. My SQL Server password is very complex. It have tried several complex passwords. It is trying to create a user from what i see and fails there 
`"CREATE USER [marketingautomationuser] WITH PASSW"`

Comment: The error might be misleading. Did you try `sitecore91234###9900` as a password?

Comment: My SQL EXPRESS password is `admin1234##9900`

Comment: can you try a strong password like 2!SiteCore . This question I would say is not related to Sitecore, is more Sql question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is related to Sql not  Sitecore

Comment: Actually it isn't @VladIobagiu. I'm betting that Sitecore generates the password for [marketingautomationuser] based on something that ends up being too short

Comment: Same error even after trying `2!SiteCore`. It has nothing to do with SQL. I can create users with same password. I have tried 5 different passwords. Very complex even.

Comment: Please checkout entire log file. I have uploaded it here: https://jsfiddle.net/statbat/osvh6urd/

Comment: @MarkCassidy Thanks a lot for supporting me. This is exactly what is happening in my humble newbie opinion. Sitecore is trying to generate very simple password for new users it is trying to create which is failing unfortunately.

Comment: Digging around a bit. Meanwhile, maybe this helps you. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12110/sif-installation-password-validation-error/12116#12116

Comment: @MarkCassidy I have tried this already. This does not help either. Everything pass all the tests.

Comment: Try defining `$SqlAdminPassword` as `$SqlAdminPassword = 'yourpassword'` instead of using double quotes (e.g. `$SqlAdminPassword = "sc9password"`)

Comment: This did not help either. I used `$SqlAdminPassword='2!SiteCore' `

Comment: I resolved this issue by changing the default TEST12345 password with a password according to my SQL Server Password Policies. Both JSON files xconnect-xp0.json and sitecore-XP0.json meed to be updated. Did you get chance to have a look at the question:- https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12056/sif-installation-throwing-password-validation-failed-exception

Comment: In that question, it is not clearly mentioned that both files should be edited. I edited one file and that didnt work. Further it is very vaguely mentioned how things should be edited.  This question can help someone in future if answer here is clear  and complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the error and the complexity of your admin password, this might be related to the password being assigned to the marketing user when it is being created. By default, I believe this is `Test12345`.

Try updating the values in your XP0 JSON config file for the passwords being assigned to the created users for each database. I have had this issue when installing on a secure installation because the default password in the JSON file was not complex enough.

**NOTE:** This applies to both `xconnect-xp0.json` and `sitecore-xp0.json` files.

Comment: I did try that. Just it seems that my edits are not coming into effect. How to correctly edit the json file? I posted this question also https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12231/how-to-edit-sitecore-xp0-json-file

Comment: The default is indeed `Test12345`: 
        "SqlMarketingAutomationPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Test12345",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Marketing Automation connection string in Sitecore."

Comment: @Sallu search for Test12345 and 12345 is the JSON files and replace the passwords respecting you SQL server password policies.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I now failed on 28th step instead of getting stuck on 15th step.

Comment: @Jay S will you please edit your answer to clearly state that both files `xconnect-xp0.json` and `sitecore-XP0.json` should be edited and value for `DefaultValue` must be changed. Your answer is right answer and I will accept just I dont want anyone else to waste 24 hours again.

Comment: Have a look at my blog, I listed all the issue I faced while installing Sitecore 9.0.1. URL: https://sitecorecompetencies.com/2018/05/31/hiccups-during-sitecore-9-xp0-installation-on-a-server/

Comment: @AmitabhVyas I am sure you would have not faced the errors I am facing. In #29 it is trying to access the file it deleted itself in previous step and then complain that `Cannot find path 'C:\sitecore\install\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 
171002 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip' because it does not exist."` :-D

Comment: Well I think you should step back and validate your pre-requisites. It seems the package path you provided in your PS1 file is incorrect.

Comment: @Sallu: I have updated my answer to have that note. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

The password for the `marketingautomationuser` account comes from the sitecore-xp0.json and xconnect-xp0.json files:

```
    "SqlMarketingAutomationUser": {
        "Type": "string",
        "DefaultValue": "marketingautomationuser",
        "Description": "The Sql user for the Marketing Automation connection string in Sitecore."
    },
    "SqlMarketingAutomationPassword": {
        "Type": "string",
        "DefaultValue": "Test12345",
        "Description": "The Sql password for the Marketing Automation connection string in Sitecore."
```

Instead of editing these files to change the `SqlMarketingAutomationPassword` default, you should instead update your installation script to provide the new password:

```
$SqlMarketingAutomationPassword = "Sup3rSecureS1tecore_pass!" 

$xconnectParams = @{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
    SiteName = $XConnectCollectionService
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
    SqlServer = $SqlServer
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl
    SqlMarketingAutomationPassword = $SqlMarketingAutomationPassword
}

$sitecoreParams = @{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
    SqlServer = $SqlServer
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName
    SiteName = $sitecoreSiteName
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"
    SqlMarketingAutomationPassword = $SqlMarketingAutomationPassword
}
```

As [Sallu](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/3808/sallu) noted in a comment, the default password for many of the automatically-created accounts is `Test12345`, which would not meet your Windows password policy requirements. By my count, there are twelve accounts Sitecore creates with the password `Test12345`. You'll need to update the above code to include all twelve of those accounts and their newer more secure passwords (or, as Sallu suggested, edit the json files directly; still not the preferred solution, but permissible in a pinch).

Comment: This looks like a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Just a comment to **future readers**. This wont work because then you will get an error `"CREATE USER [referencedatauser] WITH PASSWORD = ". Password validation failed. The password does not meet Windows policy requirements because it is too short. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587` Either you specify **all passwords for all users** using @Ed Schwehm method or just **edit DefaultValue in json file**. It is upto you.

Comment: Thanks Sallu, I updated my answer to note the other users.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go, this might solve the problem for you:

Go to: `Start > Run > type "secpol.msc"`

Then go to: `\Security Settings\Account Policies\Password Policy`

Then disable 'password must meet complexity requirements' and apply

then try again.

> obviously this should only be done on local dev environments and not
>   on other environments.

Comment: This would be a workaround however, not an actual answer

Comment: Thats true, it won't solve the problem for installs in other environments with this policy enabled. In my settings this isn't enabled and I've installed Windows 10 and SQLExpress fairly recently so I'm guessing the default is that this is off so if it's just for development machines it feels like an acceptable approach.

Comment: I think that this is not question related to Sitecore but more Windows settings so answer is fitting the purpose to help and then delete the question as no longer reproducible :)

Comment: @AdamSeabridge I did try that even before posting the question. Just I cant do it. I am local admin of the computer, but still the computer is from my employer and has this feature disabled. This was the first workaround that I tried and failed :-)

Comment: @PeterProchazka Don't you think it is a Sitecore related issue? Sitecore should be generating proper complex enough passwords so that no one run into this issue. I think this approach to just blame Windows/SQL or something else has lead to this issue in first place rather than working on to improve product itself.

Comment: I agree. Definitely a Sitecore issue, this.

Comment: Yeah it feels like the default passwords should more complex by default as you say Sallu. Perhaps there could be a parameter in the powershell script that you can set to auto-generate a long password so it is unique to each install too and then this is passed into the methods that need it. Rather than all installs having the password as a standard long password such as: 'Test12345hMfwRDvEqAsFsBa9gmtPt5Vq'

Comment: You can customize passwords that will be used during creation of users. I remember that OOTB the password for all users is set to Test1234 or something similar. If you add setting of these properties in your ps1 you could overcome this limitation. Just saying :) But agree that OOTB passwords should not be that simple. Question is what password policy has your employer. If it's too complex, then it's definetely not fault of Sitecore or Microsoft... That's why I use VMs to overcome these limitations. I do not want to add more heat to this thread. Over and out. Nice weekend ;)

Comment: In my opinion everyone have different password policies in their organization hence even providing a complex passwords by default may not work. But yes the installation guide must have some instructions to cross verify that the passwords are appropriate for the policies.